# Android WebView when refresh it always goes to home page

Tags: android, webview, refresh, pull-to-refresh

I was try to create a android webview with the refresh option.
Whenever I pull down for refresh it always goes to the home page.

I have try using the swiperefeshlayout. My code are as follows

activity_main.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/destiny"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java file

```
package com.my.project;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView myWebView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipe);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                WebAction();
            }
        });

        WebAction();
    }

    public void WebAction(){
        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.destiny);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://myurl");
        swipe.setRefreshing(true);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        AppUpdateChecker appUpdateChecker=new AppUpdateChecker(this);  //pass the activity in constructure
        appUpdateChecker.checkForUpdate(false); //mannual check false here
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url.startsWith("tel:")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }

            public  void  onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String fallingUrl) {
                myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setTitle("Loading.....");
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                setTitle(view.getTitle());
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

With this code the refresh always goes to the home page
but I want to refresh the webview on the same page itself.

Comment: You're calling `myWebView.loadUrl("http://myurl")` in your `WebAction()` method each time, instead of using the current URL the WebView is pointing to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting all variables and actions again `onRefresh()` you only need to load current url of `WebView` again. So you need to change your `OnRefreshListener` like below;

```
  swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
      @Override
      public void onRefresh() {
          myWebView.loadUrl(myWebView.getUrl());
      }
   });
```